Is rendering an LWC component multiple times efficient
An example that demonstrates my question:
I have a list of 100 items (can by of any type, but let's say it will be images).
I want to display those images inside a loop.
Would it be more efficient to display them inside a single component (main) and create an img tag inside the loop OR create another, child, component for each image and use that component inside the loop?
Or is it the same thing in terms of efficiency?
Many thanks in advance!

This is kind of a nuanced question, so the answer depends. The Lightning Web Runtime (LWR) itself is incredibly performant, being able to render many thousands of DOM elements or components with relative ease. Even 10,000 images would render in just a fraction of a second, not including whatever time it took to load that many images.
However, one twist is that Locker Service (LS) is very inefficient with iterations. The reason why is it filters the list each time you do anything with it, so 10,000 items becomes effectively 100,000,000 iterations, making it incredibly slow. Using Lightning Web Security (LWS) significantly improves performance.
See this answer of mine of an example where performance degradation is directly linked to LS. There are some mitigations available, but mostly just turning on LWS will fix most performance problems. If your users are complaining about performance, check the LWS setting.
In summary, you should use whatever design best suits your code. Having more components allows for better reuse of styles that may reduce development time, while simple elements like img tags don't need an entire component of their own, leading to less maintenance time. Particularly, when using LWS, the render time should be about the same either way.
At the size of about 100 items, the difference in performance probably doesn't matter at all. It's when you have 10,000 items or more that you can really start to feel the difference in performance, and that mostly comes from the choice of using LS over LWS. You should prefer to use LWS whenever possible, as it does a really good job of "getting out of the way" and letting your templates render well in either situation.
